# adding functions to main class from a different class using bean configuration if possible

Tags: java, class-design, javabeans

I'm writing a red5 application in Java. it just means that I have a bean that points to my main class app class that's called *Application*.

I have several classes that I want to add and remove like modules to my application.

example:

I have two classes called 'A' and 'B', each one of them contains the public function testme().
I want somehow to configure that my main Application class will call the constructor of these two classes and that somehow my main Application class will contains the functions Atestme() and Btestme() that will call the appropriate testme() function in the appropriate class. is there a way to achieve such a thing without me manually creating these functions and calling the appropriate function within one of the classes?

Is there a way to use bean configuration to achieve such a goal ? (I want to be
able to configure adding and removing 'modules' using bean configuration if possible)

I started reading about reflections, and it says that adds performance overhead and I should avoid for production environments that are time and cpu sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to catch when aDoTest() or bDoTest() is called in my main class and to catch it in order to call the appropriate functions ?

How about this:

```
public class Application {
    public static void aDoTest() {
        doTest(new A());
    }

    public static void bDoTest() {
        doTest(new B());
    }

    private static doTest(Testable t) {
        t.testMe();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aDoTest();
        bDoTest();
    }
}

public interface Testable {
    public void testMe();
}

public class A implements Testable {
    public void testMe() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If this does not help, you need to clarify your question.

---

Perhaps you are wanting to catch calls to non-existent (i.e. undeclared or unimplemented) methods and turn them into calls to real methods.  If so, you can give up on that idea.  Java won't let you do it.

The closest that you can come is to *generate* a new class at runtime with implementations for this methods:

- You can dynamically generate source code, compile it and load it.
- You can use something like BCEL to create ".class" files and load them.
- Use the [`Proxy`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class to create a dynamic proxy implementation of some interface.

But these approaches are all complicated and expensive.  (Probably a lot more expensive that using reflection, unless the generation cost can be amortized over a huge number of calls.)

Comment: thanks a lot! you clarified what I needed to know. I'll probably use a different implementation with reflections

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have **methods**, not **functions**.

Write an interface Testable.

```
public interface Testable {
    public void testme();
}
```

class A and B must implement interface Testable.

Then in your class Application you have a method

```
private static doTest(Testable t) {
    t.testme();
}
```

and then you have main() method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    doTest(new A());
    doTest(new B());
}
```

Comment: thank you for the information. is there a way to catch when aDoTest() or bDoTest() is called in my main class and to catch it in order to call the appropriate functions ?

Comment: What is aDoTest()?? I see no aDoTest in the above code. What are you talking about?

Comment: I wrote doTest() because that's what you wrote in your example. in general I want the functions in those classes to be added to the main class. so I'm asking how can I catch in a class if someone called a function that does not exist and direct him to the proper function call?

Comment: You want to call testme() on an object of type A, and then invoke testme() on an object of type B. Is that right? So, you see, class A has that method, and class B too. What do you mean by "function that does not exist"??

Comment: I meant that if a method that doesn't exist is being called in class, to catch the call and the call a different function instead according to my configuration.